# Making an echo line stay on screen for a certain time

Tags: windows, batch-file, time, line

As I said in the title i have a batch file with echo lines. I want them to stay each on the screen for a certain period of time. Could you give me an exemple of such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `sleep` command. For example:

```
SLEEP 5
```

This will delay the execution for 5 seconds.

Comment: can you give me an example of it?

Comment: i have like this line      „echo searching...” where to put the sleep command?

Comment: Just check adding this line after your echo

Comment: try this TIMEOUT /T 5

Comment: It works but I dont want to see that waiting line... There was a key to hide it...